# Javascript / AngularJS / NodeJS - Check for duplicates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a pretty tricky error....

I pass in data to a function. What the function has to do is get that data and make sure the data doesn't already exist on another page. The data on the other page is an array, and if nothing is in it gives undefined. An idea of what I want to do is below:

```
if($scope.profile.x.VALUE_IN_UNDEFINED_ARR_X === undefined)
{
   //AKA theres nothing in the profile yet...add to users profile
}
else
{
  if($scope.profile.x.name === myData.name)
  {
    //now theres a duplicate found
  }
  else
  {
    //add to users profile
  }
}
```

I can't seem to get something like this to work. For me, it is always executing the code in the first if statement (undefined). It then keeps adding duplicates.

I hope you guys can maybe help me write a loop that can fix this for me.

Thanks

Comment: What is `VALUE_IN_UNDEFINED_ARR_X`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `typeof` to check for undefined

```
typeof $scope.profile.x.VALUE_IN_UNDEFINED_ARR_X == 'undefined'
```

also, "there is nothing in the profile" can be interpreted as "`$scope.profile` is undefined", if so, you should check this

```
typeof $scope.profile == 'undefined'
```

Comment: ... or compare with `undefined` primitive like OP's doing now.